# regular vs uniform

Tags: sentence-construction

> Since the last papal reform, several
> proposals have been offered to make the Western calendar more useful or **BLANK**. Very few reforms, such as the rather different decimal French Republican and Soviet calendars, had gained official acceptance but each was put out of use shortly after its introduction.

Options for BLANK:

- regular
- uniform

I am unable to understand the difference between uniform and regular in this context.

**My Approach**

By understanding their meaning and the context of use as adjectives I found these below meanings.

uniform: Unvarying/consistant

regular: Having a constant pattern

And choose uniform because it made sense to me.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what aspect[s] of "calendar variation" you're interested in  here. That French Revolution attempt to impose a new standard with every month consisting of three 10-day weeks was never going to work (any more than the *Academie Francaise* could stop French people using ***weekend*** as a "loanword" from English). But both the vocabulary and the calendar issue are more about *the exercise of power* than about being "usefully uniform". Which aspect is *your* context concerned with? The authoritarian imposition of uniformity, or the "simplification" of a measuring system?

Comment: I would have gone for _regular_ but without even more context this is hard to answer. Is this from some sort of test or is it from a more extensive passage?

Comment: Yes it was from a test I found online and the link I found the full passage was https://calendars.wikia.org/wiki/Calendar_reform @mdewey

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I am referring this context https://calendars.wikia.org/wiki/Calendar_reform

Comment: Which agrees with my choice of  regular.

Comment: This is a really bad test - either word fits well. I suspect that "regular" is the missing word, but "Uniform" is probably a more obvious choice to a non-native, and perfectly valid.

Comment: @mdewey can you explain why regular?

Comment: The current civil calendar does not have a constant pattern. Months have different lengths, years have different lengths which have an irregular pattern., months do not contain integer numbers of weeks and nor do years. So it is irregular.

Comment: @mdewey Thanks this was helpful.

Comment: @mdewey: People have known for centuries that any attempt to "regularise" the calendar must eventually fail, unless we sever all connections to daily and annual cycles, since the relevant astrophysical phenomena don't reflect simple integer-based time divisions. It's impossible to have an integer number of days in a year, or seconds in a day. I think the boffins now make micro-second adjustments every year, because stuff like GPS relies on ultra-accurate timing. And that'll probably become even more significant when we get 6G comms in a few years time (requiring *daily* clock recalibration?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with those comments saying that this is a bad test question because neither “uniform” nor “regular” makes any sense in speaking of a calendar. “Uniform” does not technically admit of degree, but if we mean “uniform” as a synonym for “regular,” every calendar is already regular in both the sense of “having a repeating pattern” and the sense of “being constructed according to rule.” “Regular” in its patterned sense does admit of degree so it is the better of two very bad choices. I point out that the test’s text is not even grammatical (the past perfect has no reference point).

In the context of the article from which the article was drawn, it is relatively clear that “regular” in the sense of “according to rule” is what was meant (and was in fact the word used), but that still makes no sense. The Julian calendar had rules. The fact that those rules created significant error over long periods of time does not obviate the existence of rules. What, given the article as a whole, I think it was ineptly trying to say is

> to create a calendar more practically useful or with rules more easily remembered and understood.

We may doubt whether either goal alone, let alone both together, is achievable, but the sentence presenting the goals is comprehensible and grammatical.